# Where does "flying in the face" come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms

To "fly in the face of" something means to be opposite it, with a particular connotation that is hard to describe. Where does the expression come from?

Comment: I seem to recall it has something to do with how chickens will fly into the face of an attacking fox, but I'm damned if I can find a source for it.

Comment: OED has ***to fly at/on/upon = to spring with violence upon, attack with fury*** with first citation 1549. Most early printed instances of *fly in the face of...* in Google Books seem to be *...of God/Heaven*, so I kinda doubt it's an allusion to how cornered chickens behave defensively.

Comment: *If nature fly in my face first? Then nature's the aggressor.* John Dryden, [*The Spanish Friar*](http://books.google.com/books?id=qe0kAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA573&lpg=PA573&dq=if+nature+fly+in+my+face+first&source=bl&ots=6io2Ju9saU&sig=mXDqEp12_-hYP6qTqbcdiDr0cOo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_AzNU7pQlK3IBNqvgPgB&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=if%20nature%20fly%20in%20my%20face%20first&f=false), 1681.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [source](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-fly1.htm) dates it from the 1500s and says:

> ### Fly in the face of
>
> The first version, from the 1550s, was to fly in a person’s face and its literal meaning was of a dog that attacked by springing at a person. Very early on, it acquired the figurative sense of verbally attacking someone who disagreed with your opinions or your actions, decidedly getting in their face.

See also [this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fly+at) page which shows that the meaning of "to fly at" still means to attack, regardless of presence of wings or not

> Attack fiercely, assault. For example, The dogs flew at each other's throats . [Late 1500s]

Another [source](http://www.joe-ks.com/phrases/phrasesF.htm#ixzz38C0wXDqc) keeps the idea of threatening or challenging danger

> ### Fly in the face of
>
> Meaning: To go against accepted belief; to respond actively against danger.
> Example: The U.S. invasion of Iraq flew in the face of intelligence reports that stated Iraq had no weapons of mass destruction.
> Origin: This expression alludes to that of the hen that flies in the face of the dog or fox that attacks her.

Comment: The source you offer gives no other source or quote for *his* knowledge and doesn't seem to carry much weight.

Comment: The other answer seems much more likely to me. Dogs don't fly. Falcons do.

Comment: @PeterShor The phrase to fly at means to attack. See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fly for another example of the phrase "The dogs flew at each other's throats."

Answer (score 8):

According to the following source, the expression [fly in the face of](http://users.tinyonline.co.uk/gswithenbank/sayingsf.htm)  comes from falconry:

> - go against accepted wisdom, knowledge or common practice
>   An expression in use from the 19th century and *probably even earlier, from falconry, where the allusion is to a falcon or other bird of prey flying at the face of its master instead of settling on the falconer's gauntlet.*

[Fly in the face of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fly+in+the+face+of)  someone or something , also *fly in the teeth of someone or something*:

> Fig. to challenge someone or something; to go against someone or something.
>
> - This idea flies in the face of everything we know about matter and energy. You had better not fly in the face of the committee.

Source: (tinyonline.co.uk)